# How to upgrade my existing .net 4.5.2 project to DNX 4.5.1?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, dnx

In my solution I have several projects. Most of them are using DNX 4.5.1 framework. Accidentally I added a new project which is based on .net 4.5.2.

So how to upgrade it to DNX 4.5.1?

Comment: Why downvote it? I don't want rewrite the code.

Comment: Recreate the project as an ASP.NET 5 Class Library. Basically you need a project.json file to compile but if you want to open it in Visual Studio you need an xproj file instead of a csproj

Comment: My question is that I don't want recreate the new project.Actually it is a test project, can we manually to edit the project file etc.?

Comment: Yes, get any xproj and overwrite the existing one. They all have the same content. Then create a project.json file